# How to take a value from nested array(json format) without using multiple foreach in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I want to take the all id values in the json format.

```
{
"1": {
  "name": "test",
  "followup": {
    "1": {
       "id": "98",
       "followup": {
          "1": {
           "id": "93",
           "followup": {
            "1": {
             "id": "174"
            },
          }
        }
       }
     }
  }
 }
}
```

I can achieve this by using nested `foreach`. But now the 'followup' key is present in 3 but it may came 6,7 so we can't add 6,7 `foreach`.

Comment: You need to get the followup id? what must be the desired output of your example?

Comment: See [array_walk_recusive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).

Comment: you need to loop through it if you want to access that keys. I think you should try to simplify your json object, so it wouldn't be so nested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) for this, like([DEMO](https://3v4l.org/DrEdM)):

```
$ids = array();
$data = json_decode($str, true);

array_walk_recursive($data, function($v, $k) use (&$ids) {
    if ($k === 'id') {
        $ids[] = $v;
    }
}); 

var_dump($ids);
```

This basically goes through every index 1 at a time and matches the the keys against the key `id`, and if it matches it captures the value.